# Does anyone have the name of a liquid that bonds to rust and produces a hard black finish?

Tags: paint, metal

Years ago I purchased a thick substance/liquid in a small white plastic jar from Sears. It was a thick off-white liquid that one would paint onto a rusty metal surface. The liquid would change to a hard black finish that was quite strong. I cannot find it now. Does anyone know what I am searching for? It is not Rust-O-Leum. It is not a paint. It actually bonded to the rust.

Comment: You're looking for "rust conversion primer", though it may also be known under other names. Auto supply stores should have it if you can't find it anywhere else.

Comment: @keshlam I think this more than a primer. Sounds like a rust neutralizer (which can act as a primer, but it's more than just a painted coating): http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/s_trmt_extend/overview/Loctite-Extend-Rust-Neutralizer.htm

Comment: I agree that it's more than a primer, but that combination of keywords is the best i can think of to find the right stuff either online or in the store. It's sold under multiple names and brands, but if you go searching for that you'll find it.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I found it. See answer below.

Comment: @Junco Please accept the answer you gave.

Answer (score 2):

I found it by searching. It is more than a primer. It actually bonds to the rust. It somehow chemically...does something...I read about it years ago.

A user must be extremely careful working with it. You don't want it on your skin. You don't want to drop a bit of rust into the jar. You don't want to double-dip a brush into the jar. The whole container could react and harden. You pour out or scoop out some into a separate container to use what you think you will need.

Oh...Duh...The name of the product...

It is called Permatex Rust Treatment. I used it years ago on my car. It worked well. You just have to follow the instructions and heed the warnings. I remember that it worked very well. It was much better than sanding, priming and painting. It reacts and somehow bonds to the rust itself.

Comment: Reacts somehow == Phosphoric acid, iron phosphate conversion, thus "conversion primer" as @Keshlam said.

Answer (score 0):

[Por-15](http://www.por15.com/) does this too.

Do not get it on your skin: it will not come off easily.